# Transliterate between Cyrillic and Latin scripts

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, hash-map, linq

I want to get a code review on the following transliteration code.  I wrote it because there were some libraries that I have tried and they were specifically failing with the name "Yuliya" from Latin to Cyrillic. I wrote unit tests for my functions.

Things I noticed:

- I don't need it to support both standards GOST 16876-71 and ISO 9-95, because I would use it to transliterate from/to Bulgarian and if you pay attention to `CyrillicLowercase` and `LatinLowercase`, it's a bit different than these standards.
- Having `CyrillicUppercase` and `CyrillicLowercase` separately is not great. I believe [this snippet](https://github.com/gerzoid/ExcelImporterToSQL/blob/a1d53fee8d79d725393a75e3a4995d9d80168b0c/SqlFileImporter/Classes/Translit.cs#L68) solves it. I mean it doesn't have 4x const strings like I do, which is much better. It puts`.ToLower()` and `.ToUpper()` in the code.
- you might ask why I did `.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.Length)` specifically for `LatinToCyrillic` and the reason is because if you transliterate the name "Yuliya Koleva Hadzhiivanova" (Latin to Cyrillic), it won't think of `Yu` as a whole, instead it will think of it as `Y` and `u`, which would result in "Иулия..." instead of "Юлия...", which is wrong. I found that solution in [this code](https://github.com/gp-repos/old-code/blob/63c270c7971888dedf03a8248892a760b5487dbf/CommonUtils/Transliteration.cs#L63) and used it.
- I used `.Aggregate` and [this code](https://github.com/gp-repos/old-code/blob/63c270c7971888dedf03a8248892a760b5487dbf/CommonUtils/Transliteration.cs#L66) uses `.Replace`. Which one is more optimal?

```cs
public sealed class Transliteration
{
    private const string CyrillicLowercase = "а б в г д е ж з и й к л м н о п р с т у ф х ц ч ш щ ъ ь ю я";
    private const string CyrillicUppercase = "А Б В Г Д Е Ж З И Й К Л М Н О П Р С Т У Ф Х Ц Ч Ш Щ Ъ Ь Ю Я";
    private const string LatinLowercase = "a b v g d e zh z i y k l m n o p r s t u f h ts ch sh sht a y yu ya";
    private const string LatinUppercase = "A B V G D E Zh Z I Y K L M N O P R S T U F H Ts Ch Sh Sht A Y Yu Ya";
    
    private readonly Dictionary<string,string> _dict;

    private Transliteration()
    {
        _dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    private Transliteration(Dictionary<string, string> dict)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(dict);
        
        _dict = dict;
    }
    
    public static Transliteration Create()
    {
        var lowercaseDict = CyrillicLowercase.Split(' ')
            .Zip(LatinLowercase.Split(' '), (k, v) => new { k, v })
            .ToDictionary(x => x.k, x => x.v);

        var uppercaseDict = CyrillicUppercase.Split(' ')
            .Zip(LatinUppercase.Split(' '), (k, v) => new { k, v })
            .ToDictionary(x => x.k, x => x.v);

        var both = lowercaseDict.Concat(uppercaseDict)
            .ToLookup(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, g => g.First());

        return new Transliteration(both);
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Transliterates cyrillic text to latin.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">The text to be transliterated.</param>
    /// <returns>The transliterated text.</returns>
    public string CyrillicToLatin(string text)
    {
        return _dict.Aggregate(text, (current, pair) => current.Replace(pair.Key, pair.Value));
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Transliterates latin text to cyrillic.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">The text to be transliterated.</param>
    /// <returns>The transliterated text.</returns>
    public string LatinToCyrillic(string text)
    {
        return _dict.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.Length).Aggregate(text, (current, pair) => current.Replace(pair.Value, pair.Key));
    }
}
```

### xUnit

```cs
public class TransliterationTests
{
    private readonly Transliteration _transliteration;
    
    public TransliterationTests()
    {
        _transliteration = Transliteration.Create();
    }
    
    [Fact]
    public void CyrillicToLatinTextShouldEqualTheirEqual()
    {
        // Arrange

        
        // Act
        var actual = _transliteration.CyrillicToLatin("Юлия Колева Хаджииванова");

        // Assert
        actual.Should().Be("Yuliya Koleva Hadzhiivanova");
    }
    
    [Fact]
    public void LatinToCyrillicTextShouldEqualTheirEqual()
    {
        // Arrange

        
        // Act
        var actual = _transliteration.LatinToCyrillic("Yuliya Koleva Hadzhiivanova");

        // Assert
        actual.Should().Be("Юлия Колева Хаджииванова");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Dynamic vs Static lookup table

- You are recreating each and every time the same lookup table whenever someone calls the `Create` method

  - This is unnecessary since you can do it only once and without using linq

```
new Dictionary<char, string>
{
    { 'а', "a"}, { 'А', "A"},
    { 'б', "b"}, { 'Б', "B"},
    { 'в', "v"}, { 'В', "V"},
    { 'г', "g"}, { 'Г', "G"},
    { 'д', "d"}, { 'Д', "D"},
    { 'е', "e"}, { 'Е', "E"},
    { 'ж', "zh"}, { 'Ж', "Zh"},
    { 'з', "z"}, { 'З', "Z"},
    { 'и', "i"}, { 'И', "I"},
    { 'й', "y"}, { 'Й', "Y"},
    { 'к', "k"}, { 'К', "K"},
    { 'л', "l"}, { 'Л', "L"},
    { 'м', "m"}, { 'М', "M"},
    { 'н', "n"}, { 'Н', "N"},
    { 'о', "o"}, { 'О', "O"},
    { 'п', "p"}, { 'П', "P"},
    { 'р', "r"}, { 'Р', "R"},
    { 'с', "s"}, { 'С', "S"},
    { 'т', "t"}, { 'Т', "T"},
    { 'у', "u"}, { 'У', "U"},
    { 'ф', "f"}, { 'Ф', "F"},
    { 'х', "h"}, { 'Х', "H"},
    { 'ц', "ts"}, { 'Ц', "Ts"},
    { 'ч', "ch"}, { 'Ч', "Ch"},
    { 'ш', "sh"}, { 'Ш', "Sh"},
    { 'щ', "sht"}, { 'Щ', "Sht"},
    { 'ъ', "a"}, { 'Ъ', "A"},
    { 'ь', "y"}, { 'Ь', "Y"},
    { 'ю', "yu"}, { 'Ю', "Yu"},
    { 'я', "ya"}, { 'Я', "Ya"},
    { ' ', " " }
}
```

- I've also added one extra mapping (space -> space)

#### Immutability

- In your version you have used a `const string` which is immutable
- In my version if I declare a field like this `static readonly Dictionary<char, string>` then the reference is immutable but the collection itself is mutable

  - In order to make the collection immutable we can use the `ToImmutableDictionary` builder method

```
private static readonly ImmutableDictionary<char, string> cyrillicToLatinMapping = new Dictionary<char, string>
{
    { 'а', "a"}, { 'А', "A"},
    { 'б', "b"}, { 'Б', "B"},
    { 'в', "v"}, { 'В', "V"},
    { 'г', "g"}, { 'Г', "G"},
    { 'д', "d"}, { 'Д', "D"},
    { 'е', "e"}, { 'Е', "E"},
    { 'ж', "zh"}, { 'Ж', "Zh"},
    { 'з', "z"}, { 'З', "Z"},
    { 'и', "i"}, { 'И', "I"},
    { 'й', "y"}, { 'Й', "Y"},
    { 'к', "k"}, { 'К', "K"},
    { 'л', "l"}, { 'Л', "L"},
    { 'м', "m"}, { 'М', "M"},
    { 'н', "n"}, { 'Н', "N"},
    { 'о', "o"}, { 'О', "O"},
    { 'п', "p"}, { 'П', "P"},
    { 'р', "r"}, { 'Р', "R"},
    { 'с', "s"}, { 'С', "S"},
    { 'т', "t"}, { 'Т', "T"},
    { 'у', "u"}, { 'У', "U"},
    { 'ф', "f"}, { 'Ф', "F"},
    { 'х', "h"}, { 'Х', "H"},
    { 'ц', "ts"}, { 'Ц', "Ts"},
    { 'ч', "ch"}, { 'Ч', "Ch"},
    { 'ш', "sh"}, { 'Ш', "Sh"},
    { 'щ', "sht"}, { 'Щ', "Sht"},
    { 'ъ', "a"}, { 'Ъ', "A"},
    { 'ь', "y"}, { 'Ь', "Y"},
    { 'ю', "yu"}, { 'Ю', "Yu"},
    { 'я', "ya"}, { 'Я', "Ya"},
    { ' ', " " }
}.ToImmutableDictionary();
```

#### Cyrillic 2 Latin

- With this dictionary in our hand the translation is quite an easy task

```
string.Join("", text.ToCharArray().Select(c => cyrillicToLatinMapping[c])
```

- First convert the `text` to a character array
- Then loop through the array and do a lookup in a lookup table
- Finally concatenate the looked up `string`s

#### Order by latin mappings' length

- Yet again rather than doing this (re)ordering every time when someone calls the `LatinToCyrillic` method you can do it only once

```
private static readonly ImmutableArray<(string Latin, char Cyrillic)> latinToCyrillicMapping =
    cyrillicToLatinMapping
        .OrderByDescending(v => v.Value.Length)
        .Select(d => (Latin: d.Value, Cyrillic: d.Key))
        .ToImmutableArray();
```

- Here we can't simple swap the `Key` and `Value` and still use a `Dictionary` to store the result (`.ToImmutableDictionary(d => d.Value, d => d.Key)`
- Rather we could create an array with named `ValueTuple`s

#### Latin 2 Cyrillic

- With the above array in our hand the translation can be done like this

```
int startIdx = 0;
StringBuilder accumulator = new();
while (startIdx != text.Length)
{
    foreach (var (latin, cyrillic) in latinToCyrillicMapping)
    {
        if (text[startIdx..].StartsWith(latin))
        {
            accumulator.Append(cyrillic);
            startIdx += latin.Length;
            break;
        }
    }
}
return accumulator.ToString();
```

- Here iterate through the `text` by moving a pointer

  - The pointer points to the next character which has not been translated yet
- Since we have ordered `latinToCyrillicMapping` that's why we try to match (`StartsWith`) first the three letters long strings then the two letters long strings and finally the single letter long strings
- Whenever we have found a match then we add the translation to the `accumulator` and move the pointer accordingly

---

For the sake of completeness here is the fully rewritten version of your `Transliteration` class

```
public static class Transliteration
{
    private static readonly ImmutableDictionary<char, string> cyrillicToLatinMapping = new Dictionary<char, string>
    {
        { 'а', "a"}, { 'А', "A"},
        { 'б', "b"}, { 'Б', "B"},
        { 'в', "v"}, { 'В', "V"},
        { 'г', "g"}, { 'Г', "G"},
        { 'д', "d"}, { 'Д', "D"},
        { 'е', "e"}, { 'Е', "E"},
        { 'ж', "zh"}, { 'Ж', "Zh"},
        { 'з', "z"}, { 'З', "Z"},
        { 'и', "i"}, { 'И', "I"},
        { 'й', "y"}, { 'Й', "Y"},
        { 'к', "k"}, { 'К', "K"},
        { 'л', "l"}, { 'Л', "L"},
        { 'м', "m"}, { 'М', "M"},
        { 'н', "n"}, { 'Н', "N"},
        { 'о', "o"}, { 'О', "O"},
        { 'п', "p"}, { 'П', "P"},
        { 'р', "r"}, { 'Р', "R"},
        { 'с', "s"}, { 'С', "S"},
        { 'т', "t"}, { 'Т', "T"},
        { 'у', "u"}, { 'У', "U"},
        { 'ф', "f"}, { 'Ф', "F"},
        { 'х', "h"}, { 'Х', "H"},
        { 'ц', "ts"}, { 'Ц', "Ts"},
        { 'ч', "ch"}, { 'Ч', "Ch"},
        { 'ш', "sh"}, { 'Ш', "Sh"},
        { 'щ', "sht"}, { 'Щ', "Sht"},
        { 'ъ', "a"}, { 'Ъ', "A"},
        { 'ь', "y"}, { 'Ь', "Y"},
        { 'ю', "yu"}, { 'Ю', "Yu"},
        { 'я', "ya"}, { 'Я', "Ya"},
        { ' ', " " }
    }.ToImmutableDictionary();

    private static readonly ImmutableArray<(string Latin, char Cyrillic)> latinToCyrillicMapping =
        cyrillicToLatinMapping
            .OrderByDescending(v => v.Value.Length)
            .Select(d => (Latin: d.Value, Cyrillic: d.Key))
            .ToImmutableArray();

    public static string CyrillicToLatin(string text)
        => string.Join("", text.ToCharArray().Select(c => cyrillicToLatinMapping[c]));

    public static string LatinToCyrillic(string text)
    {
        int startIdx = 0;
        StringBuilder accumulator = new();
        while (startIdx != text.Length)
        {
            foreach (var (latin, cyrillic) in latinToCyrillicMapping)
            {
                if (text[startIdx..].StartsWith(latin))
                {
                    accumulator.Append(cyrillic);
                    startIdx += latin.Length;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return accumulator.ToString();
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

> In this case J is a char that cannot be found at LatinToCyrillicMapping and it is running in an infinite loop. I want to throw an exception instead of running in an infinite loop

```
var prevStartIdx = startIdx;
foreach (var (latin, cyrillic) in latinToCyrillicMapping)
{
    if (text[startIdx..].StartsWith(latin))
    {
        accumulator.Append(cyrillic);
        startIdx += latin.Length;
        break;
    }
}
if (prevStartIdx == startIdx)
    throw new NotSupportedException("...");
```

- So, here we basically check whether or not the `startIdx` has advanced if not then throw an exception

---

**UPDATE #2**

> `text[startIdx..]` allocates substring for each letter.
> Use `text.AsSpan()` and then `Slice()` it

The modified code:

```
var textSpan = text.AsSpan();
...
var prevStartIdx = startIdx;
foreach (var (latin, cyrillic) in latinToCyrillicMapping)
{
    if (textSpan.Slice(startIdx).StartsWith(latin))
    {
        accumulator.Append(cyrillic);
        startIdx += latin.Length;
        break;
    }
}
if (prevStartIdx == startIdx)
    throw new NotSupportedException("...");
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's actually more than I expected :) In addition to yours, I would also add `-` because there are names like Anna-Maria which would lead to `The given key '-' was not present in the dictionary.`

Comment: @nop Good catch :) I've tested my refactored version with your tests, I was not thinking about missing letters/special characters.

Comment: Btw, I found a bug. If someone mistypes "Jani" instead of "Dzhani", it should be transliterated to "Джани", however, "J" is not included in `LatinToCyrillicMapping`. What would be more appropriate to check if the letter exists in `LatinToCyrillicMapping`?

Comment: @nop Sorry, I'm not 100% sure what exactly is your question? Are you asking that how should you handle those cases when the `LatinToCyrillic`'s inner loop does not find a mapping?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In this case `J` is a char that cannot be found at `LatinToCyrillicMapping` and it is running in an infinite loop. I want to throw an exception instead of running in an infinite loop.

Comment: @nop Okay, give me a couple of minutes and I'll update my answer.

Comment: @nop Please check my update

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: `text[startIdx..]` allocates substring for each letter. Use `text.AsSpan()` and then `Slice()` it

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic Thanks, I've just updated my post accordingly