# Creating complex object step by step

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net, fluent-interface

> Builder pattern separates object construction from its representation

I have to generate username and password for the `Account` class. Since this operation is a bit more complex, I decided to wrap it into a Builder pattern because it allows me to create an object step by step using methods.

- FirstName and LastName are required
- MiddleName is optional.
- Faculty number is 6 digits
- Username equals to `[prefix][year of study which is the first two digits of the faculty number][name initials e.g. John Smith Mikaelson -> jsm]`
- Password is simply the faculty number, nothing complicated here

I would like to get a code review on the code and the unit tests because 1) it's another opinion 2) I'm also not sure what the naming convention is when there is no "Act".

Part of the code, i.e. the transliteration was already reviewed by Peter Csala at [Transliterate between Cyrillic and Latin scripts](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/280039/transliterate-between-cyrillic-and-latin-scripts/280045#280045)

### Snippet

```cs
public sealed class Account
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string MiddleName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Username { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public sealed class AccountBuilder
{
    private readonly Account _account;

    public AccountBuilder()
    {
        _account = new Account();
    }

    public AccountBuilder WithFirstName(string firstName)
    {
        _account.FirstName = firstName;
        return this;
    }

    public AccountBuilder WithMiddleName(string middleName)
    {
        _account.MiddleName = middleName;
        return this;
    }

    public AccountBuilder WithLastName(string lastName)
    {
        _account.LastName = lastName;
        return this;
    }

    public Account Build(string prefix, string facultyNumber)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(prefix);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(facultyNumber);

        var regex = new Regex("^[0-9]{6}$");
        if (!regex.IsMatch(facultyNumber))
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(facultyNumber), "Faculty number should be 6-digits long");
        }

        // Transliterate name
        _account.FirstName = Transliteration.CyrillicToLatin(_account.FirstName);
        _account.MiddleName = Transliteration.CyrillicToLatin(_account.MiddleName);
        _account.LastName = Transliteration.CyrillicToLatin(_account.LastName);

        // Generate username and password
        // [cs/se][year-of-study][name-initials]
        var yearOfStudy = facultyNumber[..2];
        var firstLetterOfFirstName = _account.FirstName.Length > 0
            ? _account.FirstName.ToLowerInvariant()[..1]
            : _account.FirstName;
        var firstLetterOfMiddleName = _account.MiddleName.Length > 0
            ? _account.MiddleName.ToLowerInvariant()[..1]
            : _account.MiddleName;
        var firstLetterOfLastName = _account.LastName.Length > 0
            ? _account.LastName.ToLowerInvariant()[..1]
            : _account.LastName;
        _account.Username = $"{prefix}{yearOfStudy}{firstLetterOfFirstName}{firstLetterOfMiddleName}{firstLetterOfLastName}";
        _account.Password = facultyNumber;

        return _account;
    }
}
```

```
public static class Transliteration
{
    private static readonly ImmutableDictionary<char, string> CyrillicToLatinMapping = new Dictionary<char, string>
    {
        { 'а', "a" }, { 'А', "A" },
        { 'б', "b" }, { 'Б', "B" },
        { 'в', "v" }, { 'В', "V" },
        { 'г', "g" }, { 'Г', "G" },
        { 'д', "d" }, { 'Д', "D" },
        { 'е', "e" }, { 'Е', "E" },
        { 'ж', "zh" }, { 'Ж', "Zh" },
        { 'з', "z" }, { 'З', "Z" },
        { 'и', "i" }, { 'И', "I" },
        { 'й', "y" }, { 'Й', "Y" },
        { 'к', "k" }, { 'К', "K" },
        { 'л', "l" }, { 'Л', "L" },
        { 'м', "m" }, { 'М', "M" },
        { 'н', "n" }, { 'Н', "N" },
        { 'о', "o" }, { 'О', "O" },
        { 'п', "p" }, { 'П', "P" },
        { 'р', "r" }, { 'Р', "R" },
        { 'с', "s" }, { 'С', "S" },
        { 'т', "t" }, { 'Т', "T" },
        { 'у', "u" }, { 'У', "U" },
        { 'ф', "f" }, { 'Ф', "F" },
        { 'х', "h" }, { 'Х', "H" },
        { 'ц', "ts" }, { 'Ц', "Ts" },
        { 'ч', "ch" }, { 'Ч', "Ch" },
        { 'ш', "sh" }, { 'Ш', "Sh" },
        { 'щ', "sht" }, { 'Щ', "Sht" },
        { 'ъ', "a" }, { 'Ъ', "A" },
        { 'ь', "y" }, { 'Ь', "Y" },
        { 'ю', "yu" }, { 'Ю', "Yu" },
        { 'я', "ya" }, { 'Я', "Ya" },
        { ' ', " " }, { '-', "-" }
    }.ToImmutableDictionary();

    private static readonly ImmutableArray<(string Latin, char Cyrillic)> LatinToCyrillicMapping =
        CyrillicToLatinMapping
            .OrderByDescending(v => v.Value.Length)
            .Select(d => (Latin: d.Value, Cyrillic: d.Key))
            .ToImmutableArray();

    public static string CyrillicToLatin(string text)
    {
        return string.Join("", text.ToCharArray().Select(c => CyrillicToLatinMapping[c]));
    }

    public static string LatinToCyrillic(string text)
    {
        var startIdx = 0;
        var accumulator = new StringBuilder();
        while (startIdx != text.Length)
        {
            foreach (var (latin, cyrillic) in LatinToCyrillicMapping)
            {
                if (!text[startIdx..].StartsWith(latin))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                accumulator.Append(cyrillic);
                startIdx += latin.Length;
                break;
            }
        }

        return accumulator.ToString();
    }
}
```

### Unit tests

```cs
public sealed class AccountTests
{
    [Theory]
    [InlineData("Иван", "", "Драганов", "196300", "cs19id", "196300")]
    [InlineData("Борис", "Стоянов", "Иванов", "226502", "cs22bsi", "226502")]
    public void Account_ShouldReturnAccountObject_WhenGivenName(
        string firstName,
        string middleName,
        string lastName,
        string facultyNumber,
        string expectedUsername,
        string expectedPassword)
    {
        // Arrange
        var account = new AccountBuilder()
            .WithFirstName(firstName)
            .WithMiddleName(middleName)
            .WithLastName(lastName)
            .Build("cs", facultyNumber);

        // Act

        // Assert
        account.Username.Should().Be(expectedUsername);
        account.Password.Should().Be(expectedPassword);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please link one of your previous questions where some part of the code has been already reviewed?

Comment: Btw in this case the Build method call is your Act inside the unit test.

Comment: @PeterCsala, thanks! I just linked the another code review.

Comment: @PeterCsala, if Build method call is Act, this is what I could think of https://i.imgur.com/mNt2U2r.png. Either way, I will leave the question like that.

Comment: @PeterCsala, btw I updated AccountBuilder, more specifically `var firstLetterOfMiddleName = _account.MiddleName.Length > 0 ? _account.MiddleName.ToLowerInvariant()[..1] : _account.MiddleName;` because the unit test was failing.

Comment: The` Builder` object should not be keeping a reference to the `Account` object it creates. The Builder object should not be returning a reference to itself.

Comment: @radarbob I agree with your first recommendation that the Builder should collect all the information then create a new instance of `Account` without having a direct reference on it. Regarding your second recommendation if builder methods do not return a reference to self then how would you do method chaining/fluent interface?

Comment: @PeterCsala, how can I achieve that? By having the same properties in AccountBuilder?

Comment: @nop Not properties rather with private fields.

Comment: @PeterCsala, thanks. I'm not sure I understand the following: The Builder object should not be keeping a reference to the `Account` object it creates. The Builder object should not be returning a reference to itself. 
Does that mean that everything including firstName, middleName, lastName should be private fields, or he just meant `prefix` and `facultyNumber`?

Comment: @nop I think he meant all of them.

Comment: @radarbob, did you mean I shouldn't do `_account = new Account();` and in opposed to I should keep firstName, middleName, lastName, prefix, facultyNumber as private fields? What's the difference because I've also seen people doing `private bool _built` and then checking whether the object has been built or not.

Comment: @PeterCsala, I've been looking at several source codes by the dotnet organization. https://github.com/dotnet/MQTTnet/blob/cbf413f04e9c92c9685529276b73049b473895d7/Source/MQTTnet/Client/Options/MqttClientOptionsBuilder.cs I don't think that's an issue.

Comment: @nop You will find examples for both approach. If you look at the problem from the design pattern perspective then the Build method's responsibility  is to build a new instance from the previously gathered data.

Comment: Each "create" method will instantiate a new object with its particular parameters and pass that back to the caller. The instantiated reference goes away, of course, when the "create" method goes out of scope. The `Builder` keeping any reference to the created object is not part of construction design patterns.

Comment: @radarbob, may you give a snippet for that example? I'm interested to see how you would do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `Account`

- Depending on the requirements it would make sense to make the `class` immutable by using `init` instead of `set` for the properties

  - You can even declare the `Account` as `record` and use the `with` operators inside the builder

```
public record Account(string FirstName = "", string MiddleName = "", string LastName = "", 
                      string UserName = "", string Password = "");
```

- Marking the class as `sealed` seems to me a bit too defensive

  - Based on my previous experiences class like this is usually becomes pretty soon a base class for a couple derived classes (`Student`, `Lecturer`, etc.)

### `AccountBuilder`

#### `WithXYZ`

- Most of the `With` implementations what I have seen did the followings:

  - perform some preliminary checks (like not null)
  - perform an equality check to avoid unnecessary overwrites
  - perform the overwrite if needed

```
public AccountBuilder WithFirstName(string firstName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstName))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Please provide a valid FirstName");

    if(!string.Equals(_account.FirstName, firstName, StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
        _account.FirstName = firstName;

    return this;
}
```

#### `Build`

- Most of the time the builder function should not receive any parameter

  - Since you already have a fluent interface that's why you could easily create two `WithXYZ` methods for `prefix` and `facultyNumber`
- If some properties must be set then check these first

```
public Account Build()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_account.FirstName) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_account.LastName))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("FirstName, LastName must be set");
    //...
}
```

- You can move the Regex to class level and make it `static`

  - Even you can set `RegexOptions` to `Compiled`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm struggling with `WithXYZ` for `prefix` and `facultyNumber`. Does that mean that I should put Prefix and FacultyNumber properties in AccountBuilder?

Comment: @nop If they should not be externally available, because they are used only inside the `Build` method then it is enough to declare them as private fields.

Comment: Here is what I did based on the suggestions https://pastebin.com/9yWac2Ju

Comment: I was given the following information `Returning a ref to itself is fine, especially if you like fluent syntax.
Holding a reference to the generated object can be more problematic. You have to be careful how the builder and the object are used. Normally I would create the object only within the Build method.` `In your case, yes. I use builders mostly for tests. In your domain code, your invariants should be already protected via constructor/factory methods/methods.`

Comment: @nop What shall I do with this information?

Comment: I asked a few Microsoft associates as well. They all said that I should be creating the `Account` instance in the Build method, and not keeping it as a readonly field. Here is final code: https://pastebin.com/e3PkDHRB. You can take a look if you have anything else to mention. Otherwise I believe you can update your answer with it, because it will definitely help others :)

Comment: @nop I think my suggestions in my post are orthogonal to that question whether do you want to store a reference to the to-be-built object or not. Or why do you want me to alter my review?

Comment: You're probably right. Let's keep it that way.